# multiply every element in numpy.array a with every element in numpy.array b

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two `numpy.array`s `a` and `b`,

```
c = numpy.outer(a, b)
```

returns an two-dimensional array where `c[i, j] == a[i] * b[j]`. Now, imagine `a` having `k` dimensions.

- Which operation returns an array `c` of dimension `k+1` where `c[..., j] == a * b[j]`?

Additionally, let `b` have `l` dimensions.

- Which operation returns an array `c` of dimension `k+1` where `c[..., i1, i2, i3] == a * b[i1, i2, i3]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`outer` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) of NumPy ufuncs treats multidimensional input the way you want, so you could do

```py
np.multiply.outer(a, b)
```

rather than using `numpy.outer`.

All solutions suggested here are equally fast; for small arrays, `multiply.outer` has a slight edge

[image]

Code for generating the image:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def multiply_outer(a, b):
    return np.multiply.outer(a, b)


def outer_reshape(a, b):
    return np.outer(a, b).reshape((a.shape + b.shape))


def tensor_dot(a, b):
    return np.tensordot(a, b, 0)


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: (np.random.rand(n, n), np.random.rand(n, n)),
    kernels=[multiply_outer, outer_reshape, tensor_dot],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(7)],
)
b.save("out.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be using `np.outer` and then `reshape` -

```
np.outer(a,b).reshape((a.shape + b.shape))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `np.tensordot` also works

```
c = np.tensordot(a, b, 0)

inds = np.reshape(np.indices(b.shape), (b.ndim, -1))
for ind in inds.T:
    ind = tuple(ind)
    assert np.allclose(a * b[ind], c[(...,) + ind])
else:
    print('no error')
# no error
```

Answer (score 1):

[np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) is what you are looking for.

`c[..., j] == a * b[j]`

should be

`c = np.einsum('...i,j -> ...ij', a, b)`

and `c[..., i1, i2, i3] == a * b[i1, i2, i3]` should be

`c = np.einsum('i,...jkl -> ...ijkl', a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for kroneker product

for example

```
> np.kron(np.eye(2), np.ones((2,2)))

array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```